# How to fix AWS EC2 Status check showing "Instance reachability check failed"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

Since 3 days the second status check has failed and says "Instance reachability check failed", The first check is a pass. Please guide on how to fix this issue.

Few details of the instance are as mentioned below:

1. Instance type: t2.small
2. Platform: Ubuntu(Inferred)
3. Platform Details: Linux/UNIX

[image]

Comment: Create new instance.

Comment: What does the [logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html#troubleshooting-retrieve-system-logs) say?

Comment: Can you try to stop and start it?

Comment: most of the time stop/start of the instance work out of the box, as you mentioned you have `t2.small` instance not sure if that is using `instance store` or has an EBS volume, depending on that you might wanna make backup of the stuff on your instance if you happen to have something there.  [here is the answer from aws knowledge-center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-status-check-failure/)

Comment: @samtoddler rebooted the instance and its resolved, Thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments `rebooting` the instance helped.

Just in case if anyone else stumbles upon this on in future:

[Amazon EC2 now performs automatic recovery of instances by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html)

> A recovered instance is identical to the original instance, including the instance ID, private IP addresses, Elastic IP addresses, and all instance metadata. If the impaired instance has a public IPv4 address, the instance retains the public IPv4 address after recovery. If the impaired instance is in a placement group, the recovered instance runs in the placement group. During instance recovery, the instance is migrated as part of an instance reboot, and any data that is in-memory is lost